# does gitlab provides any pre-defined URLs/endpoints for webhooks

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I was going through gitlab docs for webhooks but did not find how to setup the URL/endpoint.
If there are no pre-defined URLs then I have to create / manage URLs/endpoint,  it is overhead because I have to manage the infrastructure and the write the code as well to create the endpoints .

So, are there any pre-defined webhooks ? , if yes , how to get that ?

further, my exact requirement is, whenever, merge request gets merged, I have to update one of the gitlab pipeline job to proceed further. is that possible through webhooks and event API ? if yes, any documentation for that please ? I see that webhook receiver is there but not sure if that will solve my requirement.

please suggest

Answer (score 1):

The URL/endpoints configured in webhooks are designed to be received by external applications, either made by you or third parties. As stated in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html):

> Usually, you set up your own webhook receiver to receive information from GitLab and send it to another app, according to your requirements.

In other words, GitLab itself has no endpoints you can point to that will respond to a webhook you configure on the repo, aside from the few builtin receivers, like for slack notifications which are configured through [integrations](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/overview.html).

> whenever, merge request gets merged, I have to update one of the gitlab pipeline job to proceed further. is that possible through webhooks and event API ?

Yes it's possible, but in order to get the effect you want, you'll have to implement the HTTP service endpoint to receive the webhook yourself.